# How to run a 'venv' from Pyscripter 3.6.1 (using Python 3.7.4)

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv, pyscripter, python-3.7

I can't access my 'venv' virtual environments from PyScripter 3.6.1. This environment was created from Python 3.7.4. I'm not particularly sure whether this is an error with my 'venv' setup, or PyScripter, or something else. (As a result, I'm not even sure if I've posted this question in the right location. That said, similar questions are all either antiquated or unhelpful for the given problem.) The problem is repeatable.

After running `py -m venv env` in the desired directory, the venv env folder appears to be intact. Running Idle while it is activated has proven successful, and the command `where python` reveals the appropriate venv installation. It contains the following:
[env folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XKLH.png)

- 'Include' folder, empty
- 'Lib' folder, with 'site-packages' folder inside
- Scripts folder, with many familiar folders/files, including the python executable
- pyvenv.cfg

After opening Pyscripter 3.6.1, I am only able to select from my standard Python installations. I take it this is expected. However, when I choose 'Setup Python Versions' and then 'Add a new Python version', I am not able to use the 'env' file as an Unregistered Version of Python. I noticed that Script contains the typical executable, but using that folder yields the same result. PyScripter tells me this: [PyScripter: Python version not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH5sx.png)

"PyScripter could not find a usable Python installation at the specified path. Note that the 64-bit version of PyScripter (x64) works only on a 64-bit Windows **and** with 64-bit versions of Python. The 32-bit version of PyScripter works on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows with 32-bit versions of Python."

I am using 64-bit Windows, 64-bit PyScripter, and 64-bit Python. Given that there is effectively nowhere online that attempts to address my issue (or at least I can't find it), I'm hoping I have a simple problem. Regardless, any help would be appreciated.

P.S. This same issue has been replicated across 4 different machines. All with 64-bit Windows 10. I'm currently running on Windows 10 Education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Pyscripter version 3.6.2 which provides better support for python venv virtual environments.